# Join two functions on google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this function which auto puts in the date in the second colum, but i need it to work on a second sheet. It now doesnt work.. How do i join them on the one function to work

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Contracts Log" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}

function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Contracts Log" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Both functions look identical... What are the names of the sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Both functions are the same so

```
function onEdit() {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Contracts Log" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue() === '') {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

This works on more than one sheet you can easily add more

```
function onEdit() {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["Contracts Log","Sheet2"];
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName()) && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue() === '') {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

- [Bitwise Not (~)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Answer (score 0):

This might be done by applying a small change to the first onEdit function: use a second comparison expression and the OR operator (`||`) on the first if statement. Discard the second onEdit function because functions names should be unique otherwise only the last one to be loaded by the runtime engine will be effective.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Contracts Log" || s.getName() == "Name of the other sheet") { //checks that we're on Sheet1 , Sheet2 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 1) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === '') //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```